Website Crawling and Indexing Issue
I find these issues on my website :

Crawled - currently not indexed Google systems
Discovered - currently not indexed  Google systems

Yesterday, I posted a blog and did bookmarking but it is not crawl or index.
Even my website's last crawling is on 24 still not crawling
All traffic is decreased and ranking is down
What should I do ???

This is very often in new websites with small traffic. Is your website new ? Do you have submitted your sitemap to GSC ? A good hint for new websites is to create artificial traffic either from Google Ads or from searching your website.
Αll the above is understood to apply provided that robots txt working that you can check theris status here https://technicalseo.com/tools/robots-txt/

yes it has only 7 months. and also submitted a sitemap too

What is the average daily traffic of your website ?

According to Semrush Tool, my website latest traffic is 22 visitor

If your sitemap is ok add an inbound link from your homepage to the the blog to speed up the procedure . If you want share your link for a more detailed answer
